# Crystal Reports pagination problem

Tags: crystal-reports, pagination

we use Crystal Reports 9 and want to improve the automatic pagination for printing.

We have the following structure in our report:

- Group

  - Subgroup

    - Entry in Subgroup
    - Entry in Subgroup
    - Entry in Subgroup

The whole group appears on the current page if all entries of the subgroup fit on the current page. That's ok.
If the subgroup has more entries and there isn't enough space on the current page left then the whole group will be pushed to the next page. That's not ok.

We don't want half of the pages empty and we don't want this either:

- Group

  - Subgroup

******************new Page******************

- Entry in Subgroup
- Entry in Subgroup
- Entry in Subgroup

We want to put the group only on the current page if at least one entry of the subgroup fits to the current page. Like this:

- Group

  - Subgroup

    - Entry in Subgroup

******************new page******************

- Entry in Subgroup
- Entry in Subgroup

Is there a way to achive this with Crystal Reports 9. We would even get Crystal 2008 if necessary.

Thanks and greetings
Juergen

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at [Keep Together](http://www.crystalkeen.com/articles/crystalreports/blankpages.htm) option?

Answer (score 0):

@Juergen, Your problem looks that Group Header or Detail section property KeepTogether,GroupKeepTogether are not correctly set.
Set KeepTogether = False
GroupKeepTogether = None

Comment: but if I deactivate KeepTogether it may happen what I described above. Group and subgroup could be on one page and their entries on the next page. I don't want that either. I want the groups be together if at least one entry fits to the current page. 
I need a rule like: keepTogether if 1 sub entry fits to page, but put the whole group on next page if it doesn't.